# How to test destroy failure in controller using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a books controller with the following action...

```
def destroy
   @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   if @book.destroy
     redirect_to(books_path)
   else
     render('delete')
   end
 end
```

I am able to test the the first if case, but not the situation where @book.destroy returns false. My question is - how do I make @book.destroy fail? I want to write a rspec test to cover that case.

```
describe "destroy" do
   before(:context) do
     @book = create(:book)
   end
   context "failing the destroy function" do
     it "renders delete" do
       allow(@book).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)
       delete :destroy, params: { id: @book.id }
       expect(response).to render_template(:delete)
     end
   end
 end
```

I tried writing the above thinking that allow(@book).to receive(:destroy).and_return(true) would make destroy() return false, but instead, it still returns true and tests the code in the first if statement. I have no idea how to cover the code in the else statement. Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't be `.and_return(false)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason your test does not work is that `Book.find` will load the record from the database and create a new instance of the class which means that `#destroy` is not being called on the same object that you have stubbed.

You need to stub the `Book.find` method so that it returns the book instance with the stubbed method:

```
describe "destroy" do
  context "failing the destroy function" do
    let(:book) { build_stubbed(:book) } # use let instead of ivars

    # don't use before :context unless you actually 
    # have a real reason. You should strive to have 
    # each example setup/teardown on their own 
    before do
      allow(book).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)
      allow(Book).to receive(:find).and_return(book)
    end 

    it "renders delete" do
      delete :destroy, params: { id: book.id }
      expect(response).to render_template(:delete)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: there's a typo on `receive`